# split violin plot for a lung function (continuous) comparing distance with overly plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, stat

I'd like to make a split violin plot for a lung function (continuous) that compares distance (its categorical variable, i.e., two categories) in children and adults, as well as overly crude and adjusted means (lung function: code given below) with 95%CI / B coefficients with 95% CI from a linear regression model on it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```r
# Regression model

crude <- lm(lungfunction~distance, data = dummy_data) summary(crude)
adjusted <- lm(lungfunction~distance+age+edu+no2+pm25, data = dummy_data) summary(adjusted)

# Crude and adjusted mean lung function 

library(lsmeans)
library(emmeans)
  
# Crude mean lung function
crude_mean <- aov(lungfunction~distance, data = publication_dummytable2)
                summary(crude_mean)
                 lsmeans(crude_mean, 'distance')
 
 
# Adjusted mean lung function
 
adjusted_mean <- aov(lungfunction~distance+age+edu+no2+pm25, data = publication_dummytable2)
summary(adjusted_mean)
lsmeans(adjusted_mean, 'distance')
```

Here is some example data

```r
structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 51L, 
52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L
), age = c("child", "child", "adult", "child", "adult", "adult", 
"adult", "child", "child", "adult", "child", "adult", "adult", 
"adult", "child", "child", "adult", "child", "adult", "adult", 
"adult", "child", "child", "adult", "child", "adult", "adult", 
"adult", "child", "child", "adult", "child", "adult", "adult", 
"adult", "child", "child", "adult", "child", "adult", "adult", 
"adult", "child", "child", "adult", "child", "adult", "adult", 
"adult"), sex = c("M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", 
"M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", 
"M"), distance = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", 
"a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"b"), edu = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "x", "x", "x", 
"y", "y", "y", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "x", "x", 
"x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "x", 
"x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z"
), lungfunction = c(45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 23L, 25L, 
45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 
70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 
69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 
45L), no2 = c(40L, 70L, 50L, 60L, 30L, 25L, 80L, 70L, 50L, 60L, 
30L, 25L, 80L, 89L, 50L, 60L, 30L, 25L, 80L, 89L, 10L, 60L, 30L, 
25L, 80L, 89L, 10L, 40L, 30L, 25L, 80L, 89L, 10L, 40L, 70L, 25L, 
80L, 89L, 10L, 40L, 70L, 50L, 80L, 89L, 10L, 40L, 70L, 50L, 60L
), pm25 = c(15L, 20L, 36L, 48L, 25L, 36L, 28L, 20L, 36L, 48L, 
25L, 36L, 28L, 15L, 36L, 48L, 25L, 36L, 28L, 15L, 25L, 48L, 25L, 
36L, 28L, 15L, 25L, 15L, 25L, 36L, 28L, 15L, 25L, 15L, 20L, 36L, 
28L, 15L, 25L, 15L, 20L, 36L, 28L, 15L, 25L, 15L, 20L, 36L, 48L
)), row.names = c(NA, -49L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you don't need to load the lsmeans package. Even the lsmeans() function is in emmeans.

Comment: @ Russ Lenth, thank you for your comment. What would be the best way to answer the question, and how would I calculate adjusted means?

Comment: I don't know how to answer the question. Some ggplot virtuoso may be able to say how to do the plot and somehow indicate the adjusted means. Note that summary(lsmeans(,..)) produces a data.frame, so that's how to access the needed values. Actually predict(lsmeans(...)) would give you just those means.